# AWS APIGateway WebSockets API returns 429

Tags: websocket, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I am load-testing a WebSocket Service which I deployed today on AWS APIGateway using a tool called [Thor](https://github.com/observable/thor). The service uses Lambda based message handlers and is packed and deployed through Serverless framework in Python3.8. The connection ids are stored in DynamoDB.

My AWS account level throttle is currently at 10000 requests/second and bursts are at 5000.

I'm getting the below results for 2000 concurrent connections with 1 message per connection:

```
Online               4353 milliseconds
Time taken           4353 milliseconds
Connected            1826
Disconnected         0
Failed               174
Total transferred    549.23kB
Total received       420.84kB

Durations (ms):

                     min     mean     stddev  median max
Handshaking          840     1629        666    1448 3383
Latency              103     198         150     155 859

Percentile (ms):

                      50%     66%     75%     80%     90%     95%     98%     98%    100%
Handshaking          1448    1930    2178    2297    2497    2641    3311    3336    3383
Latency              155     163     167     172     194     665     785     798     859

Received errors:

174x                 unexpected server response (429)
```

It's clear that the requests are being throttled at this point. I want to know what should be my account level throttle limit for supporting 20,000 concurrent WebSocket connections. Sometimes, I also see `500` errors in the results which I'm unable to debug from the logs.

Let me know if more information is needed to answer this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a limit of 500 WebSocket connections per second on API Gateway.
Check here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/limits.html

It is possible that you are running into these limits.

Comment: Thanks, @vijtrip2. This checks out.